# FosJSRoutingBundle, route does not exist

Tags: symfony, fosjsroutingbundle

I'm trying to generate URL in my Javascript but I can't due to this error:

> Error: The route "my_route" does not exist.

I don't know why but the route is not recongnized...

What I did:

1) Get the bundle by composer 
2) Published the assets :

```
php bin/console assets:install --symlink public
```

3) Use this in JS:

```
Routing.generate("my_route")
```

4) And then, this in my controller:

> ```
>     /**
>      * @Route("/route/to/route",  options = { "expose" = true }, name="my_route")
>      * @param Request $request
>      * @return Response
>      */
>     public function my_route(Request $request){ 
> some things...  };
> ```

So, it's not working...

I checked the JS dependencies that are loaded in the page:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js') }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

The first work but the second return error 404... Why ?

Regards

Comment: clear the cache, after can you look if your route exist with command bin/console debug:router

Comment: Already cleared the cache and the route is well shown in bin/console debug:router ...

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html#generating-uris

Comment: Oh, it's working with Apache server but, If I launch the server only with PHP (php -s 127.0.0.1 -t public) it's not working... any idea ?

Comment: I don't know why.. maybe have you got a .htaccess into public folder ?

Comment: run this command `bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/js/fos_js_routes.json`

Comment: @tolgakaragol not working.. I don't think that it's related to my code directly but it's serverside